# Android: Cannot set TextView for Title

Tags: java, android, textview

I am using the technique brought up in previous `StackOverflow` questions, which suggest using `TextViews` and setting properties in them as the parameter for `setTitle` in an `AlertDialog`. I need this so I can style the `font` of the title.

The problem is that `Android Studio` says that it

```
cannot resolve method android.widget.TextView
```

Below is my code:

```
  TextView settingsTitle =  new TextView(this);
    settingsTitle.setText("Settings");
    settingsTitle.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromFile("monospace"));

    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle(settingsTitle)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // continue with delete
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // do nothing
                }
            })
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
            .show();
```

Comment: There is no method setTitle which accepts TextView, check docs:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code as

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle(settingsTitle.getText().toString())
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // continue with delete
                }
            })
```

as there is no such method called `setTitle()` which has an argument of type `TextView`.

Thus use, `settingsTitle.getText().toString()` which gets the String in the `TextView` and use that to set the title like

```
setTitle(settingsTitle.getText().toString())
```

Read more about it in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence))